# Is there an equivalent to the wcwidth() function in Go?

Tags: unicode, go, terminal, rune

The POSIX function `wcwidth()` computes the width of a given `wchar_t` when printed on a terminal. For instance, `wcwidth(L'A')` returns `1`, `wcwidth(L'字')` returns `2`, etc. There is also a function `wcswidth()` which computes the width of an entire string—this is useful if combining accents are present.

Does a similar function exist in the Go standard library or the supplementary libraries? If not, is there an easy way to make something sufficiently similar?

Comment: You may also be interested in the [`golang.org/x/text/width`](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/text/width) package, which is part of the
[Go project's sub-repositories](https://golang.org/pkg/#subrepo). There is also a (possibly) related Go project [blog article](https://blog.golang.org/normalization).

Comment: @DaveC Ah! That must be new. Maybe that package's existence is a consequence of the bug I filed about the absence of these functions?

Comment: I don't think it offers the same functionality however, it just may be of interest as it's related.

Comment: @DaveC It does exactly what wcwidth does—classifying characters with respect to size on terminal devices.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Does a similar function exist in the Go standard library or the supplementary libraries?

I believe the most popular library for this is [go-runewidth](https://github.com/mattn/go-runewidth).

Example:

```
package main

import (
  "github.com/mattn/go-runewidth"
)

func main() {
  println(runewidth.StringWidth("A"))   // prints 1
  println(runewidth.StringWidth("字"))  // prints 2
}
```

Comment: After extensive testing, I can confirm that this library does what I need. Thank you!